# dockerfile not using the docker compose service correctly

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Why does my dockerfile keeps throwing the below error where i am simply doing a sqlplus command using the db service in the docker-compose so that it connects to the same container.
The same command works when on the container.
Any thoughts...

docker-compose:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  db:
    image: oracle19c:new
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
      - ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB1
      - ORACLE_PWD=password
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      #- oracle:/opt/oracle/oradata
      #- ./scripts:/scripts
      #- ./software:/software
      - ./scripts/:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup/
      - ./utPLSQL-develop/utPLSQL-develop/:/tmp/utPLSQL/
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 190

  utplsql:
    build: ./
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
      - ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB1
      - ORACLE_PWD=password
```

#######################################

dockerfile:

```
FROM oracle19c:new

# Setup ORACLE ENV
ENV ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
ENV ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB1
ENV ORACLE_PWD=password

# Set up the command to wait for the Oracle DB, then install utPLSQL
CMD sqlplus sys/password123@db:1521/ORCLPDB1 as sysdba @/tmp/utPLSQL/source/install_headless.sql
```

#########################################

error when building:

```
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Oct 12 16:25:30 2023
compose-utplsql-1  | Version 19.3.0.0.0
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | ERROR:
compose-utplsql-1  | ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | 
compose-utplsql-1  | Enter user-name:
compose-utplsql-1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: You are accessing the listener locally (inside the container) - so use 'localhost' instead of the docker-compose service construct 'db'

Comment: Dockerfile does not use **anything** from docker-compose and cannot access the DB during the build because the DB is not running yet.

Comment: Bjarte - The utlplql service defined in the docker-compose, is acting as a separate service  and shows as a separate container. defining "localhost" would not attach it to the correct container?

Comment: Pino - may be my understanding is wrong, thats how i have constructed the docker compose to wait for the db service to complete and then run the utlplsql , which is in the dockerfile. what is your recommendation?

Comment: The error says the listener is up at least; and it isn't saying the DB isn't up yet (unknown), but it seems to be losing the service name `ORCLPDB1` after the second `/` in the command somehow.

Comment: @Raj24, sorry it was not clear to me that the `Dockerfile` refers to the `utplsql` service.

Comment: Official [Docker images of Oracle DB](https://container-registry.oracle.com/) have a support to execute some scripts on startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be flexible in what scripts to run after database is created, use gvenzl's images. These are awesome and made for developers!

```
cat > docker-compose.yml <<EOF
version: "3.9"

services:

  oracle:
    container_name: oracle-free
    image: gvenzl/oracle-free:latest
    environment:
      ORACLE_PASSWORD: Welcome_#1
      APP_USER: dev
      APP_USER_PASSWORD: dev
      TARGET_PDB: FREEPDB1
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - ./init_scripts:/container-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: healthcheck.sh
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
EOF
```

Create your script folder and add your scripts

```
mkdir init_scripts

# utilize the new 23c dev role 'db_developer_role'

cat > init_scripts/01_grant_db_developer_role.sql <<EOF
alter session set container=freepdb1;
grant db_developer_role to dev;
EOF
```

The Oracle Database startup routine is configured to eat all scripts in this folder

```
tree init_scripts/
init_scripts/
└── 01_grant_db_developer_role.sql

1 directory, 1 file
```

Bring up the database service

```
docker compose up -d
```

Login as app user 'dev'

```
export TWO_TASK=localhost/FREEPDB1
sqlplus dev/dev

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Oct 13 07:15:00 2023
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Oct 13 2023 07:12:18 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 23c Free, Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Developer-Release
Version 23.2.0.0.0

dev@FREEPDB1>
```

Was I assigned the new 23c role?

```
dev@FREEPDB1> select granted_role, admin_option, default_role
  2  from
  3    user_role_privs
  4  order by granted_role;

GRANTED_ROLE         ADM DEF
-------------------- --- ---
CONNECT              NO  YES
DB_DEVELOPER_ROLE    NO  YES
RESOURCE             NO  YES

3 rows selected.
```

From here, you can load up the whole internet into your Oracle Database.

Best of luck!